# Passing variables from one form to another in vb6

Tags: vb6

Am developing this program where the user has to enter some strings and integers in a form then the same variables are used to generate output in another form. How do I pass the variables from the first form to the other? I've tried using modules but it still doesn't work. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a global variable (in a form `Public gRtfHwnd As Long`). If you have multiple forms use `frmName.VarName`.

Comment: @ACatInLove A public variable in a form isn't considered a global variable in VB6, since, as you have mentioned, you have to reference the form in order to access the variable from somewhere in the project other than the form itself. So, it's actually considered an attribute of the form's interface. If you want a global variable, you have to add a standard module and put a public variable there.

Comment: "How do I pass variables from one form to another?" seems a clear statement of the problem to me. Furthermore, I don't see how the OP would create an example of what he doesn't know. I think the voters noticed that the OP committed the "doesn't work" sin and automatically put it on hold because of that. Seems a bit of a rush to judgment to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that you have a TextBox called myTextBox on Form1. Let's also say that you have a CommandButton on Form1 called myCommandButton. Finally, let's also say that you have a label called myLabel on Form2.

If you want the contents of your text box to appear on the label on the other form when the user pushes the button:

```
Public Sub myCommandButton_Click()
    Form2.myLabel.Caption = myTextBox.Text
End Sub
```

I think what you're not clear on is that you can reference any of the controls on another form by first referencing the other form. Don't use a module for this; you don't need it. Think of each form as an object (which it is) and the public variables in the form as properties of the object (which they are). That way, the syntax should become clear to you.

You may not be aware that in your form's code, you can reference one of your form's controls in any of these three ways:

```
myControl
myForm.myControl
Me.myControl
```

So, you can, say, call one of a control's methods using any of these three syntaxes:

```
myControl.myMethod
myForm.myControl.myMethod
Me.myControl.myMethod
```

The form reference defaults to the current form. So, if you want to reference a control on another form, you have to specifically reference the other form along with it.